# App Engine dev server: bad runtime process port [''] No module named google.appengine.dist27.threading

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When I try to run any of my app engine projects by python GoogleAppEngineLauncher
I got the error log as follows:

Does anyone have any ideas of what's going on?
I tried remove the SDK and reinstall it. Nothing happens. Still got the same error.

Everything is working fine and I don't think I made any changes before this happens.
The only thing that I can think of is that I install bigquery command line tool before this happens. But I don't think this should be the reason of this.

`bad runtime process port ['']`

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File 
>   "/Users/txzhang/Documents/App/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py",
>   line 197, in 
>       _run_file(**file**, globals())   File "/Users/txzhang/Documents/App/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py",
>   line 193, in _run_file
>       execfile(script_path, globals_)   File "/Users/txzhang/Documents/App/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime.py",
>   line 175, in 
>       main()   File "/Users/txzhang/Documents/App/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime.py",
>   line 153, in main
>       sandbox.enable_sandbox(config)   File "/Users/txzhang/Documents/App/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py",
>   line 159, in enable_sandbox
>       **import**('%s.threading' % dist27.**name**)   File "/Users/txzhang/Documents/App/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py",
>   line 903, in load_module
>       raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname) ImportError: No module named google.appengine.dist27.threading

Comment: It might help people to have a little context surrounding this question.  Adding things like, did it ever work and what changed when it stopped working, would be helpful.

Comment: Everything is working fine and I don't think I made any changes before this happens.
The only thing that I can think of is that I install bigquery command line tool before this happens. But I don't think this should be the reason of this.

Comment: It doesn't sound like that is your issue.  I wish I had more to offer.  Good luck.

Comment: For anyone else, try running with the flag `--allow_skipped_files 1`

Answer (score 3):

The most probable reason is having another python package that is coming from google. Run 
python in verbose mode with `python -vvvvv` and try following command `import google`.

If the above import is successful make sure its coming from  `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google` which is the path of python google appengine libraries on my system (OSX, fresh install of google appengine sdk).

If that is not the case *(but the import is successful)* then its most likely other existing google libraries which are creating issue and the path of the same would be visible on python prompt after the successful `import google` command like following:

> >>> import google
>
> import google # loaded from Zip
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/protobuf-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/google/**init**.pyc

In this case my google protobuf package was the culprit.

**Solution:**

1. **Use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)**: If you haven't used python virtualenv before, may be this is the best time to use it. **(a)** Make sure that your `PYTHONPATH` variable is not set to include anything that has a google package! Unset it running `unset PYTHONPATH` (in your bash prompt) unless you are very sure what you have there. **(b)** Create a new python virtualenv, activate it and try to run google appengine commands in it:

   ```
   virtualenv --no-site-packages /tmp/googleapps
   source /tmp/googleapps/bin/activate
   dev_appserver.py path_to_google_app
   ```
2. **Remove conflicting packages from path:** Move conflicting packages a new virtualenv. This is likely to break other stuff so **not recommended**.

---

I had hit the same issue today. This being the top result on google but lacked any answers, I add this after fixing same issue on my system. There may be other possible reasons which thankfully I haven't come across.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this really saved me a lot of time! I also had an old protobuf package installed

Answer (score 1):

A recent upgrade of the development SDK started causing this problem for me. After much turmoil, I found that the problem was that the SDK was in a sub-directory of my project code. When I ran the SDK from a different (parent) directory the error went away.